# Newly created VM not appearing in VM List

Tags: azure, azure-vm

I am just starting out familiarising myself with Azure and have created my first VM. The creation process worked fine and I was able to start up the VM and access it remotely without a problem. On my Azure dashboard the VM I created is shown in the "All Resources" block and if I hover over the "Virtual Machines" link in the Azure menu the popup shows the new VM as a "Recent resource".

If I click on Virtual Machines and go to the Virtual Machines page the list is empty. All filters are turned off yet my newly created VM does not appear in the list. Have I done something wrong in my VM creation? What would cause a VM not to appear in the list of VMs yet show up as an available resource in my dashboard? FYI my account is currently on a free trial.

Comment: you just have to wait a couple of minutes

Comment: In fact the same applies to anything I create. The resource will appear on the dashboard but will not appear in the specific list, i.e. if I create a virtual network it will appear in the resource list on my dashboard but the Virtual Networks page is always empty.

Comment: something is obviously wrong with what you do. try using incognito mode and test the same thing, but like i said, this is working fine, just need to wait a couple of minutes for the resource to appear

Comment: wait for some time and hard reload your browser. You can also raise support ticket for this from azure portal.

Comment: VM was created 3 hours ago. Browser stopped and restarted. VM still not appearing in list but does appear in dashboard and in Recent resources in the VM hover popup. Will raise a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted support and they said it was a problem on their side with the portal. Problem is resolved today.